# Dart optional parameter is null type

Tags: dart, asynchronous, types, null

I'm trying to use optional parameter default value in my function in dart, but it causes error `Error: Not a constant expression.`

I tried to solve with inserting my variable to a lambda function that returns `int`, but it didn't worked. See my code

```
Stream<int> testAsync(int n, {int delay = 100}) async* {
  if (n > 0) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(microseconds: delay));
    yield n;
    yield* testAsync( n-1 );
  }
}
```

is there a way to use optional int in Delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `const` on the `Duration` constructor. There are no issues with your use of optional parameters.

Dart cannot create a compile-time constant from a potentially variable function argument.

```dart
Stream<int> testAsync(int n, {int delay = 100}) async* {
  if (n > 0) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: delay));
    yield n;
    yield* testAsync( n-1 );
  }
}
```